# Nested Array in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to design the above attached screen shot and I am getting a response in this format,

```
"data": {
  "personaldata": [
    {
      "name": "suresh",
      "time": [
        {
          "start": 12: 00,
          "end": 16: 00
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to show the data as shown in the screen shot, please let me know how can I achieve this

Comment: What have you tried? Or do you know where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function for your use. You can map over the data and get corresponding values and display as text.
A basic implementation for same is as follows:

```
<View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
      }}>
      {data.personaldata.map(item => {
        // uncomment below line to see what item is
        // console.log(item);
        return (
          <>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            {item.time.map(item => {
              return (
                <Text>
                  {item.start} {item.end}
                </Text>
              );
            })}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </View>
```

Here I have applied map over `data.personalData` which gave me data for each `user/entity` and then again apply map over `item.time` which gives start and end time for each index.

Answer (score 0):

if the data is a lot like more than a thousand use flatlist because it will only render a few data.

```js
    <Flatlist
     data={data.personaldata}
     renderItem={({item})=>{
     return(
     <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-beetwen',paddingHorizontal:20}}>
         <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <View>
       {item.time.map((time)=>{
        return (
           <Text>{time.start}-{time.end}</Text>
        )
       })}
       <View>
     </View>
     )
     }}
    />
```